# Can a WebRTC connection be established between two apps on the same client and window?

Tags: javascript, network-programming, webrtc

Although WebRTC is meant for conference calls, it's possible to [capture a `MediaStream` and use that as a source for an `RTCPeerConnection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream). As it happens, this could be a solution to a problem I'm facing: displaying a live-stream in a WebGL app that doesn't support them.

(The idea is to use a library like HLS.js to handle assembling and remuxing the live-stream, and then stream that video into my WebGL app. The app's built in Unity, the game engine, [which has introduced a package for WebRTC](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.webrtc@2.3/api/Unity.WebRTC.html), so I'd be able to display that.)

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Connectivity), a server is required to act as a middleman between clients. From what I understood, however, this is essentially to help them find each other and agree to connect over a P2P network. Since the two apps—the WebGL app and a Node app/JS script—live on the same client, even the same browser window, maybe I could omit the middelman and connect directly?

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything regarding this method—probably because it's such an unusual use-case. Is it possible? If so, is it feasible, and how might it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be possible...  The signaling server acts as a go between so you can exchange the SDP and IceCandidates.  If both of your peer connections are in the same application (javascript?) you should be able to pass those objects directly.

For example

```
conn1 = new RTCPeerConnection();
conn2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

conn1.onicecandidate = (event) => {
  if (event.candidate) {
     conn2.addIceCandidate(event.candidate);
  }
}

conn2.onicecandidate = (event) => {
  if (event.candidate) {
     conn1.addIceCandidate(event.candidate);
  }
}

conn1.createOffer()
    .then(offer => conn1.setLocalDescription(offer))
    .then(() => conn2.setRemoteDescription(conn1.localDescription))
    .then(() => conn2.createAnswer())
    .then(answer => conn2.setLocalDescription(answer))
    .then(() => conn1.setRemoteDescription(conn2.localDescription))
    .catch(handleCreateDescriptionError);
```

EDIT:  I just read that they're in different apps.  You would have to find another method of passing this information between the apps, but as long as you can exchange this data, the connection should work.

Comment: Passing the information is not a problem: Unity lets you interact with browser scripts from its own, C# scripts. I'll try this out when I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to achieve WebRTC connection without having an actual signaling server.

WebRTC itself does not care how you provide it with Offer, Answer and Ice Candidates, but I don't see a "normal" way of exchanging this information without using a signaling server.